# Usage of compression on WCF web service and gSOAP

Tags: wcf, web-services, gsoap

I wish to add compression to the WCF based web service to reduce the payload and increase throughput. But the issue is that I consume the service from a c/linux application using gSOAP. I know gSOAP allows compression, but I am not sure if gSOAP and WCF based web service can talk to each other with compression on.

Please put forward your experiences and help me.

Regards,
Kangkan
http://www.geekays.net/

Comment: Can somebody really help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you generate a gSoap client based on the WSDL file for the WCF service? What you can do is configure the WCF service to use compression and then generate the gSoap client. If client and server communicate, it worked.

However, compression is not a standard WCF feature. I suppose you use a basicHttpBinding or a wsHttpBinding in which case you can use [MTOM](http://www.w3.org/TR/soap12-mtom/) (Message Transmission Optimization Mechanism). MTOM is an interoperable standard so gSoap should support it.

You could also try to extend your binding with a GZIP encoder. Microsoft has a [sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751458.aspx) for this scenario. However, I suppose gSoap doesn't support this.